# Running Hasura console is not working from docker

Tags: docker, graphql, hasura

I have a ruby on rails app which I run via `docker-compose up`. I'm a complete noob in graphql and hasura and I've tried different ways to configure my docker but I cannot make it work.

My docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
    version: '3.6'

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgis/postgis:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "5434:5432"
        volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        environment:
          PG_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
          
      graphql-engine:
        image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.2.cli-migrations-v2
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "8081:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./metadata:/hasura-metadata
        environment:
          HSR_GQL_DB_URL: "postgres://postgres@postgres/db-dev-name"
          HSR_GQL_ADMIN_SECRET: secret
        env_file:
          - .env
          
      server:
        build: .
        depends_on:
        - "postgres"
        command: bundle exec rails server -p 8081 -b 0.0.0.0
        ports:
          - "8080:8081"
        volumes:
          - ./:/server
          - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
          - node_modules:/server/node_modules
        env_file:
          - .env
          
    volumes:
      gem_cache:
      node_modules:
```

config.yml:

```yaml
    version: 2
    endpoint: http://localhost:8080
    metadata_directory: metadata
    actions:
      kind: synchronous
      handler_webhook_baseurl: http://localhost:8080
```

Docker logs server shows:

```
Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8081
```

And I can access the app after docker-compose up  at http://localhost:8080/server/

Checking database connection, it is also reachable at port :5434 in a database manager GUI.

But when I try to execute `hasura console --admin-secret secret`, hasura console on browser is not showing. I am just getting this error on different logs:

- docker logs server:

```
    Started POST "//v1/query" for 172.25.0.1 at 2021-04-10 17:53:08 +0000
          
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/v1/query")
```

- docker logs postgresql:

```
17:27:33.453 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
17:27:33.453 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
17:27:33.453 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
17:27:33.459 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
17:27:33.467 UTC [103] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-10 17:27:33 UTC
17:27:33.473 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
17:27:41.250 UTC [111] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_extension_name_index"
17:27:41.250 UTC [111] DETAIL:  Key (extname)=(postgis) already exists.
17:27:41.250 UTC [111] STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis
17:27:47.565 UTC [116] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_extension_name_index"
17:27:47.565 UTC [116] DETAIL:  Key (extname)=(pgcrypto) already exists.
17:27:47.565 UTC [116] STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto"
17:28:01.619 UTC [128] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "acct_status_pkey"
17:28:01.619 UTC [128] DETAIL:  Key (status)=(new) already exists.
17:28:01.619 UTC [128] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "acct_status" ("status") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "status"
```

- docker logs graphql-engine: last few lines.

```json
{"kind":"event_triggers","info":"preparing data"}}
{"type":"startup","timestamp":"2021-04-10T17:28:15.576+0000","level":"info","detail":{"kind":"event_triggers","info":"starting workers"}}
{"type":"startup","timestamp":"2021-04-10T17:28:15.576+0000","level":"info","detail":{"kind":"telemetry","info":"Help us improve Hasura! The graphql-engine server collects anonymized usage stats which allows us to keep improving Hasura at warp speed. To read more or opt-out, visit https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/guides/telemetry.html"}}
{"type":"startup","timestamp":"2021-04-10T17:28:15.576+0000","level":"info","detail":{"kind":"server","info":{"time_taken":2.384872458,"message":"starting API server"}}}
```

I tried accessing http://localhost:8081//console/api-explorer via browser, and it seems the graphql container is getting the request but still wont display hasura console

```json
{
    "type": "http-log",
    "timestamp": "2021-04-12T03:24:24.399+0000",
    "level": "error",
    "detail": {
        "operation": {
            "error": {
                "path": "$",
                "error": "resource does not exist",
                "code": "not-found"
            },
            "request_id": "6d1e5f04-f7d4-48d6-932e-4cf81bdf9795",
            "response_size": 65,
            "raw_query": ""
        },
        "http_info": {
            "status": 404,
            "http_version": "HTTP/1.1",
            "url": "/console/api-explorer",
            "ip": "192.168.0.1",
            "method": "GET",
            "content_encoding": null
        }
    }
```

I've tried setting the HSR_GQL_DB_URL to either postgres / localhost:5432 as well as postgis:// instead of postgres://.
I've also tried changing config.yml endpoint field to http://localhost:8080/server/ but those were also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a bit too late, but here goes anyway:

According to the documentation under [*GraphQL engine server config reference -> Command config*](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/deployment/graphql-engine-flags/reference.html#command-config) you need to set the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE` environment variable to enable the console served at `/console`. Alternatively for the `hasura serve` command, set the `--enable-console` option to `true`:

> | Flag | ENV variable | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | `--enable-console <true|false>` | `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE` | Enable the Hasura Console (served by the server on `/` and `/console`) (default: false) |
> | ... | ... | ... |

So for your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
...
      graphql-engine:
        image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.2.cli-migrations-v2
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "8081:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./metadata:/hasura-metadata
        environment:
          HSR_GQL_DB_URL: "postgres://postgres@postgres/db-dev-name"
          HSR_GQL_ADMIN_SECRET: secret
          HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true" # add this
        env_file:
          - .env
...
```

I also read somewhere to make sure to quote `true` and `false` values when using environment variables in Docker related situations. This has worked for me, so I would stick with it. Try it out.